# How to query the actual app version string?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

The CFBundleVersion key retrieves the "Build" number set in Xcode 4, but not the "Version".

I want to get the version string that users see on the App Store. Is there a different key for this?

```
NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Comment: Use `CFBundleShortVersionString`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `CFBundleShortVersionString?`

`[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]`